# how to generate random size array for sorting visualizer purpose using html css js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, visualizer

[Array_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gijN.png)

I am currently working on a project sorting visualizer and I need help for the array generation like in the given picture. please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: simple but interesting

Answer (score 2):

This functions will generate for you an array of random length with random number (with the ranges you determine), you can use it in your visualizer.

```js
function createRandomSizeArray(minArrayLength, maxArrayLength, minColumnHeight, maxColumnHeight){
   let ArrayLength = getRandomInt(minArrayLength, maxArrayLength);
   let arr = new Array(ArrayLength);
   for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
      arr[i] = getRandomInt(minColumnHeight, maxColumnHeight);
   }
   
   return arr;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

console.log(createRandomSizeArray(5, 10, 2, 100));
```